Side by side instead of Top Down Picture Position
I write latex with IEEEtrans with TexLive version 2022.
I would like to arrange these two pictures side by side (left and right) instead of top and down picture position.
Here is the code for top and down picture position.
\documentclass[journal]{IEEEtran}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure*}
        \setkeys{Gin}{width= 2.5 in}
        \centering
        \subfloat[]{
            \includegraphics{square.png}
            \label{fig:square}}    
      
        \subfloat[]{
            \includegraphics{circle.png}
            \label{fig:circle}}
        \caption{Comparison between (a) Square and (b) Circle}    
        \label{fig: Comparison}
\end{figure*}
\end{document}


What needs to be modified on the code so that the picture position can be side by side like this?

Thank you.

Easy: Just replace the blank line between the two subfloats with a suitable spacing directive, e.g., \quad or \qquad. Remember: In TeX's text mode, an all-blank line creates a paragraph break.

... or put a % in the blank line if you want to keep some visual separation.
